# Why coord_map() overrides dup_axis() in ggplot and how to work around it

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis

I'm a little puzzled with the behavior of `ggplot2::coord_map()`. Concretely I would like to know why it seems to override `ggplot2::dup_axis()` and how can I work around it.

Let's have a look with the following reproducible examples:

**Example 1:** Using `ggplot2::dup_axis()` to obtain lat/long axis all around the map:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::map_data("france")) +
  ggplot2::geom_polygon(ggplot2::aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                        color = "black",
                        fill = "white",
                        size = .2) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ggplot2::dup_axis()) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = ggplot2::dup_axis())
```

[image]

**Example 2:** Using `ggplot2::coord_map()` to avoid distortions:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::map_data("france")) +
  ggplot2::geom_polygon(ggplot2::aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                        color = "black",
                        fill = "white",
                        size = .2) +
  ggplot2::coord_map()
```

[image]

**Example 3:** Using both `ggplot2::dup_axis()` and `ggplot2::coord_map()` to duplicate axis while avoiding distortions:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::map_data("france")) +
  ggplot2::geom_polygon(ggplot2::aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                        color = "black",
                        fill = "white",
                        size = .2) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = ggplot2::dup_axis()) +
  ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = ggplot2::dup_axis()) +
  ggplot2::coord_map()
```

[image]

The goal would be to be able to produce maps formatted as the one in example 1 but using `ggplot2::coord_map()` to avoid distortions. **All approaches to work around this issue are welcome**.

Comment: ggplot only supports multiple axis with Cartesian  coordinate systems - see comment from Hadley here https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2291

Comment: That solves "the why" then! thank you @Greg

Comment: Depending on the size of your desired maps, you may find `coord_quickmap` an acceptable Cartesian alternative to `coord_map`.

Comment: Thank you @Z.Lin insofar as my territories are not that far from the equator, `coord_quickmap` seems to be a nice workaround